# cross domain iframe resize for firefox 3.6.10

Tags: javascript, iframe

Is there any way to resize a cross domain iframe according to its content, that would work in `Firefox 3.6.10`?
I thought that the postMessage command works, but a solution I found works in `Firefox 12` but not in `Firefox 3.6.10`. Or maybe that's not the problem.

As I wrote in another question, `youtube` seems to be just embedding the content of the iframe in the page for the comment section, that's how it gets resized dynamically. And this would basically solve every iframe issue too, since the HTML would be embedded in the website's local HTML, and no same origin policy would block anything. When I asked about this, I didn't get answers though.

So thank you in advance, or if you don't like when people say that, I would be grateful if someone would helped.

And I CAN control the content inside the frame too!

(I need this for a script that makes youtube look like around 2012, so more people could be grateful too.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution i found/modified:

in the page which contains the iframe:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function resizeCrossDomainIframe(id, other_domain) {
    var iframe = document.getElementById(id);
    window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
      if (event.origin !== other_domain) return; 
      if (isNaN(event.data)) return; 
      var height = parseInt(event.data) + 32; 
      iframe.height = height + "px";
    }, false);
  }
```

in the iframe code:

```
<iframe id="my_iframe" onload="resizeCrossDomainIframe('my_iframe', '**whatever domain your iframe content is on**');"></iframe>
```

for continuous resizing, i put this in the page containing the iframe:

```
<script>

var interval = setInterval(function(){
resizeCrossDomainIframe('my_iframe', '**whatever domain your iframe content is on**');
}, 100);
</script>
```

on the iframe content page:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  window.parent.postMessage(document.body.scrollHeight, '**whatever domain your iframe containing page is on**');
}
</script>
```

and this for continuous resizing:

```
<script>

var interval2 = setInterval(function(){
window.parent.postMessage(document.body.scrollHeight, '**whatever domain your iframe containing page is on**');
 }, 100);
</script>
```

CORRECTION: the first interval script isnt needed, since the eventlistener executes the function every time a message is sent to it. it would just cause slowness

Comment: I thought you issue was that PostMessage didn't work in FireFox 3.6?

Comment: i thought so. but seems like it does

Answer (score 0):

You might try looking at this on GitHub.

https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer

Comment: Seems you need to upgrade to at least FireFox 6. Why are you bothering with such an old version of the browser?

Comment: its the best version for me... i found a solution though, should i post it there?

Comment: Please add you solution with the 'Add Another Answer' button.

Comment: added it now. sorry for  being late